# Assign keyboard shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'd like to assign a keyboard shortcut to my application, like <kbd>F1</kbd> through to <kbd>F12</kbd> each when pressed, a certain command or procedure is executed, regardless of which field or button is on focus. This should work like when for example a certain button is on focus and you press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. I am using VB 2013.

Comment: Just copy the title of your question into the Google search box to find out how to do this.  You don't even have to fix the spelling error :)

Comment: It's a bad idea to replace certain function buttons with your own.  For instance, **F1** is considered the *Help* key in many applications.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the KeyDown event of your form and with that you can capture the key and add a command to it.

Then you use a if statement to check which button is pressed and add a command for it for every button you want to use.

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.F1 Then
        MsgBox("F1")
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.F2 Then
        MsgBox("F2")
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.F3 Then
        MsgBox("F3")
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.F4 Then
        MsgBox("F4")
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.F5 Then
        MsgBox("F5")
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.F6 Then
        MsgBox("F6")
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.F7 Then
        MsgBox("F7")
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.F8 Then
        MsgBox("F8")
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.F9 Then
        MsgBox("F9")
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.F10 Then
        MsgBox("F10")
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.F11 Then
        MsgBox("F11")
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.F12 Then
        MsgBox("F12")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
 If e.KeyCode = Keys.I And e.Modifiers = Keys.Shift Then
      '' What will happen when you press Shift + I
 end if
end sub
```